# YAML syntax error when running "heroku run rake db:migrate" on my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, yaml, syntax-error

I've searched every solve for this problem for hours but I just can't get it to work.

I have a Rails app and I'm trying to deploy it to heroku, but when I run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /app/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 7 column 3
```

I already used a [YAML validator](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator) to validate my `database.yml`, but it still does not work. Here is how it looks like:

```rb
# database.yml
--- 
default: 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
development: 
  adapter: postgresql
  database: chamada_development
  encoding: unicode
  password: "<%= ENV['CHAMADA_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: chamada
production: 
  adapter: postgresql
  database: chamada_production
  encoding: unicode
  password: "<%= ENV['CHAMADA_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>"
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: chamada
test: 
  adapter: postgresql
  database: chamada_test
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```

How can I solve this? I have no clue.

Comment: Line seven is `  adapter: postgresql` in the development section, right? Are you sure that's two spaces (and nothing else) before `adapter`? What does `cat -vet database.yml` say?

Comment: The reason may be in the encoding. For example, there may be BOM. If Windows you will not see it. Create a new document in UTF-8 format and repeat.

Comment: Have you been able to deploy your app to heroku at all?  Do you have a DB config?  Do you see a `DATABASE_URL ` if you run `heroku config --app <yourappname>`  ?

Comment: @muistooshort I believe it is just 2 spaces, I don't know tough. I don't get nothing strange running `cat -vet database.yml`, just some `$` at the end of each line where they should be.

Comment: @mechnicov How do I specify the encoding when creating a file? And you mean create another `database.yml`?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes, I was! But I got an error after deployed and realized I needed to migrate the database. I'm getting this error after following this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5

Comment: Yes, I mean to replace by new `database.yml`. To specify encoding you can choose Save with UTF-8. You can do it for example in Sublime or other text editor

Comment: @mechnicov It is already in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Without BOM, non-breaking space or other symbols? I recommend to make new file with manual input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it starting over the step by step to deploy the App in Heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes in line

```
  password: <%= ENV['CHAMADA_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

You have used double quotes, so it was like:

`"<%= ENV["` `CHAMADA_DATABASE_PASSWORD` `"] %>"`

That's why error.

Comment: Try to remove double quotes in password. You also have spaces in the end of all lines, remove them. And check spaces in the beginning of all the lines.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  I have not worked on Heroku for a while, however I found an old project with these notes in my database.yml file:

```
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

You will probably need to make sure you have the environment variables set correctly.  Check by running `heroku config --app <your-app-name>`

You should not need `----`

If you're going to set default you might as well use it to not repeat yourself.  And also use single quotes and remove string interpolation.  You can add blank lines between each group.

```
default: &default 
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS') { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default 
  database: chamada_development
  password: <%= ENV['CHAMADA_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
  username: chamada

production: 
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

test:
  <<: *default
  adapter: postgresql
  database: chamada_test
```

Comment: 3 dashes, blank line between groups and DRY should not affect errors

Comment: @mechnicov It really does not. Sorry, but I already tried with (possibly) all possible layouts changing double and single quotes, removing and putting back the default and everything... It just does not work and I don't know why... I just tried lacostenycoder 's solution and still it doesn't work.